Docker compose error when configuring sysctl "vm.vfs_cache_pressure": sysctl "vm.vfs_cache_pressure" is not in a separate kernel namespace: unknown
Context
I am trying to run docker compose up -d --build an exisiting successfully built project (by docker-compose build), namely DeathStarBench which is a system for running multiple microservices to interact with each other (can be found in this Github repository).
The following code shows the content of Dockerfile:
FROM golang:1.21 as builder

WORKDIR /workspace

COPY go.sum go.sum
COPY go.mod go.mod
COPY vendor/ vendor/

COPY cmd/ cmd/
COPY dialer/ dialer/
COPY registry/ registry/
COPY services/ services/
COPY tls/ tls/
COPY tracing/ tracing/
COPY tune/ tune/

COPY config.json config.json

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GO111MODULE=on go install -ldflags="-s -w" -mod=vendor ./cmd/...

Moreover, in the docker-compose.yaml, for each microservice in this repository, we have included some records to set some sysctl configurations like net.ipv4.tcp_rmem. For example, for recommendation microservice, we have the following records in the docker-compose.yaml file:
  # <other services configuration> 

  recommendation:
    configs:
      - source: server_config
        target: /config.json
    environment:
      - TLS
      - GC
      - JAEGER_SAMPLE_RATIO
      - LOG_LEVEL
    build: .
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=16384
      - net.ipv4.tcp_wmem=65536
      - vm.vfs_cache_pressure=104
    image: deathstarbench/hotel-reservation:latest
    entrypoint: recommendation
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-recommendation
      - consul
    restart: always
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
  
  # ...

  volumes:
    # ...

    recommendation:

    # ...
  configs:
    server_config:
      file: ./config.json

The running platform is Ubuntu 22.04 and Docker version 26.1.1, build 4cf5afa.
Problem
When running docker compose up -d --build without vm.vfs_cache_pressure configuration for microservices, everything is going fine. Yet, by having this configuration, I got the following error:
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: 
failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: 
sysctl "vm.vfs_cache_pressure" is not in a separate kernel namespace: unknown

However, when running sysctl -a command on the system I can see vm.vfs_cache_pressure as a variable there.
Question
The question is how to configure this sysctl option for each microservices (with their own volumes) in docker?

Your docker-compose.yml is wrong at sysctls section. Yml file must not contain =. You should change that section like below:
sysctls:
      net.ipv4.tcp_rmem: 16384
      net.ipv4.tcp_wmem: 65536
      cpu.cfs_quota_us: 104


@VirendraJadeja Thanks for the feedback. By the way, it is working for net.ipv4.tcp_rmem=16384 for example. Moreover, if you change = to :, you will get an error in the building time of the container as the sysctls command should be a string.
